# Three vector subspaces: intersections and sums

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional $k$-vector space and let $A,B,C$ three subspaces such that $A\supseteq B$.

> Why is the following equation true?
>
> $$\dim(A/B)=\operatorname{dim }\left(\frac{A+C}{B+C}\right)+\operatorname{dim }\left(\frac{A\cap  C}{B\cap C}\right)$$

I was able to prove only that: 
$$\operatorname{dim }\left(\frac{A+C}{B+C}\right)=\operatorname{dim }\left(\frac{A}{A\cap(B+C)}\right)$$

$$\operatorname{dim }\left(\frac{A\cap C}{B\cap C}\right)=\operatorname{dim }\left(\frac{B+(A\cap C)}{B}\right)$$

Comment: What you mean by $A + B$?

Comment: the vector subspace generated by $A$ and $B$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because of the short exact sequence:
$$0\to (B+C)/B\to (A+C)/B\to (A+C)/(B+C)\to 0$$
which implies the dimension of the middle term is the sum of the dimensions of the left and right terms, and the second isomorphism theorem:
$$(B+C)/B\simeq C/B\cap C.$$

Answer (score 2):

Use:

- If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $S$ is a subspace of $V$, then $$\dim{V/S}=\dim{V}-\dim{S}$$
- If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $A$ and $B$ are subspaces of $V$, then $$\dim{(A+B)}=\dim{A}+\dim{B}-\dim{A\cap B}$$